# Java missing libraries

Tags: java, import

I'm using Eclipse on Mac OS X 10.6.6.

For some reason when I'm trying to import the following libraries I get this error:-

```
java.apt (only java.apt.font is available)
javax.swing
```

The system is fully updated with the recent updates

Thanks in advance

Comment: if only you could paste code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing

```
import javax.swing;
```

or are you doing

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

The difference is very important.

As a general rule, I try to import only the exact classes I need.

Comment: I know the difference, it shows me all the libraria under javax.swing and there are no libraries